# how search between date using post in codeignitier

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Dear Expert need Help first see my view code in codeigniter :

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tglawal" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periode</label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="input-group date">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
       <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tglawal" id="tglawal">                 
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="input-group date">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
         </div>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tglakhir" id="tglawal1">                 
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this my model code :

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
    {       
        //add custom filter here
        if($this->input->post('tglawal'))
        {
        $this->db->where('b.tglawal', $this->input->post('tglawal'));
        }
            if($this->input->post('tglakhir'))
            {
                $this->db->where('b.tglakhir', $this->input->post('tglakhir'));
            }
    }
public function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

and my controller if i get the important code is:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('infokunjungan_view', $data);  
        } 
        else redirect(base_url());
    }

    public function ajax_list()
    {
    $list = $this->Infokunjungan->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $infokunjungan) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = "<td style='vertical-align:middle'><center>{$no}<center></td>";
    $row[] = "<td style='font-size:9px; vertical-align:left;'>{$infokunjungan->tglawal}<center></td>";
    $row[] = "<td style='font-size:9px; vertical-align:left;'>{$infokunjungan->tglakhir}<center></td>";
    $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->Infokunjungan->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->Infokunjungan->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,                        
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);      
    }
```

the problem is if searching between two date tglawal and tglakhir

im using between 2016-12-04 and 2016-12-04 output display will empty
but if using between 2016-12-04 and 2016-12-06 output success where is my problem or maybe im using where or i have to use like?

Comment: can u help me with the code?

Comment: this my code : if($this->input->post('tglawal'))
  {
   $this->db->where('b.tglawal', $this->input->post('tglawal'));
  }
  if($this->input->post('tglakhir'))
  {
   $this->db->where('b.tglakhir', $this->input->post('tglakhir'));
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the >= and <= operator.

In your model try the below.

```
if($this->input->post('tglawal'))
 {
    $this->db->where('b.tglawal >=', $this->input->post('tglawal')); //assuming this is your begining (from) date
 }
 if($this->input->post('tglakhir'))
 {
  $this->db->where('b.tglakhir <=', $this->input->post('tglakhir')); //assuming this is your end(to) date
 }
```

The above will search for the between dates including the dates selected.
Use the operator depending on the beginning and ending variable.

Comment: Hi, also you might have to consider searching within the same table.field. Because you are searching in 2 different date fields in what I can see. It would be best if the search is between either b.tglawal >= $this->input->post('tglawal') and b.tglawal <= $this->input->post('tglawal').

Comment: Hi Ela, thanks before its mean simulation Where b.tglawal between '12/04/2016 00:00' and '12/06/2016 00:00' so using b.tglawal >= $this->input->post('tglawal') and b.tglawal <= $this->input->post('tglawal')

Comment: @WahyuArtadianto can you show me what you are trying? Also, I was mentioning that you were looking in to table fields where as you should be doing your date BETWEEN comparison with one field.

Comment: im trying to use if($this->input->post('tglawal'))
 {
    $this->db->where('b.tglawal >=', $this->input->post('tglawal')); //assuming this is your begining (from) date
 }
 if($this->input->post('tglakhir'))
 {
  $this->db->where('b.tglakhir <=', $this->input->post('tglakhir')); //assuming this is your end(to) date
 }

Comment: but how to use from ur code using between tglawan and tglakhir

Comment: So both tglawan and tglakhir  need to be between the search dates? And you have only 1 "from" date and 1 "to" date?

Comment: i have two input <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tglawal" id="tglawal"> and <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tglakhir" id="tglawal1">

Comment: And you want to search where the table.tglawal field is between the form's tglawal and tglakhir as well as table.tglakhir field between the form's tglawal  and tglakhir ?

Comment: if($this->input->post('tglawal'))
 {
    $this->db->where('b.tglawal >=', $this->input->post('tglawal')); $this->db->where('b.tglawal <=', $this->input->post('tglakhir'));  //assuming this is your begining (from) date
 }
 if($this->input->post('tglakhir'))
 {
  $this->db->where('b.tglakhir <=', $this->input->post('tglawal')); $this->db->where('b.tglakhir >=', $this->input->post('tglakhir'));//assuming this is your end(to) date
 }